# Adding sites to Google Search Console via API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-search-console

I have a site that has hundred of sub-domains. I need to add these sub-domains to google search console via api and using cron job with php language script.

Can you please take a look at my code bellow and let me know what is wrong with it. There is no error message but it does not add the sub-domain to the right account. Thank you!

```
<?php
    if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
        throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
    }
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'My_key';
    $client = new Google_Client();

    $client->setApplicationName("MyProjectName");
    $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('file.json');

    $scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters');
    $client->setScopes($scopes);

    $url = "http://sub.example.com";
    $webmasters = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
    $webmasters->sites->add($url); // my problem is here
    print_r( $webmasters->sites->listSites()); //works fine, gets back sub-domain
?>
```

Comment: i am suprised it works at all it looks like you are using a public api key which wont work with private data.

Comment: Thank DalmTo! The api key that you see here is fake one because I can not show my real key to the public.

Comment: the data you want to access is private you should be using oauth2. it shouldn't work at all with an API key

Comment: Yes, It works. thank you. I used the the example in this page and modified it to fit my needs. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Comment: I still need to verify the ownership of the site and submit the sitemap. The verification is little tricky since there is no direct method. Any suggestion?

Comment: Ok I found interesting blog post that helps: https://blog.ghost3k.net/articles/php/66/using-the-google-site-verification-api-in-php but for me I found that I do not need to verify the ownership of the sub-domains since I already verified the ownership of the top domain. I still have to submit the sitemap. I will post my finds for others.